# Passing a Java object from one Struts action to another

Tags: java, forms, struts, action, struts-1

In one of my Struts action I've got the following code in a method:

```
  ...
  List<Object> retrievedListOfObjects = c.getListOfObjects();
  return mapping.findForward("view");
}
```

`fw_view` leads to a new Struts action with another Struts form. Let's say this form has got among others the following field

```
List<Object> listOfObjects;
```

I now want to pass the `retrievedListOfObjects` from within the first Struts action to the form of the following Struts action.

Is this possible without storing it in the session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can store it as a request attribute.

```
request.setAttribute("listOfObjects", listOfObjects);
```

and then in the Action that is forwarded to

```
List<Object> listOfObjects = (List<Object>)request.getAttribute("listOfObjects");
```

Given that when setting request attributes you can give them meaningful names, you should consider setting many attributes rather than setting one big list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Correction of krock code.

Setting object to request:

```
request.setAttribute("listOfObjects", listOfObjects);
```

Getting the object in an other action.

```
List<Object> listOfObjects = (List<Object>)request.getAttribute("listOfObjects");
```

Comment: thanks @Fred, I fixed up the getter which I obviously cut and pasted from the setter code.