# How to preserve class type when passing object between Struts actions?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have an Object in one of my Struts action classes that is a List of Lists of Maps. So, `List<List<Map>>`

In a JSP page, I iterate over the root list and display entries on a page. I have a form that submits the selected entry to a different action.

```
<s:iterator id="searchResult" status="rowStatus" value="dataList">
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left">
            <s:form method="post" theme="simple">
                <s:hidden name="account" value="%{top}" />
                <s:submit value="Select" action="AccountSelect" theme="simple" />
            </s:form>
        </td>
        <td class="text-left">
            <s:property value="top[0].name"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

When iterating, everything is fine, but after I select the current list in the iterator to submit through the form, the type changes. I am expecting the next action to receive a List of Maps (List), but instead it receives a List of the String representation of the map.

Is there a way to preserve the type when passing between action classes? Is there a better way to do this? [Is something like this acceptable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052273/passing-a-java-object-from-one-struts-action-to-another)

Comment: what is the definition of List of Map ?

Comment: `List<List<Map>>` doesn't work with default struts type conversion, you need to rethink the design.

Comment: @RomanC yeah seems like it. Thank you.

Comment: @shantaram_t a list of maps?

Comment: `List<Map<String, String>>` ?